# Open ConEmu with /Dir is overriden by startup Task

Tags: conemu

I have a startup task that looks like this:

Command

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i "-new_console:t:Git Bash"`

Parameter

`/Single /Dir "C:\Dev\SOMEPATH" /icon "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\etc\git.ico"`

I have a command (coming from a Visual Studio "external tool", if that matters) to open a new console at a current directory.

`C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe /Single /Dir DIRNAME`

If ConEmu is already open a new tab is opened at the correct directory. If ConEmu isn't open then the Startup tasks for Git shows up instead. How can I ensure that I always get the command I am requesting in a new tab, even if ConEmu isn't already open?

Answer (score 0):

**From the build 140908 whats-new**

> Give more weight to "/dir" ConEmu.exe switch than the same from Task
>   parameter.